# Как добавляются 3 точки, когда текст не вмещается в оболочку

Tags: html, javascript, css

Например, как в ютубе

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Обрезаем длинную стро...](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/obrezaem-dlinnuyu-stro)

```
white-space: nowrap; /* Отменяем перенос текста */
overflow: hidden; /* Обрезаем содержимое */
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```